# OpenGL strange view after putting on Content Filter

Tags: xcode, cocoa, opengl

I tried to put on a Content Filter through Interface Builder, and removed it later. But after that here stays strange effect for OpenGLView:
[image]
How can I remove it?

P.S. It changes on resizing window. Sometimes, after starting app the whole screen is messy, but when i resize window it gones and changes to one witch is shown in foot

Comment: This looks like you don't clear the color buffer before drawing.

Comment: I clear it. With:     `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`